# Flutter, insert textfield into sqflite

Tags: flutter, textfield, sqflite

I'm trying to fill in sqflite tables using textfields, but it creates a separate table instead of filling in the various fields

```
class _InputBarState extends State<InputBar> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  final _controller2 = TextEditingController();
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  String get text => _controller.text.trim();
  String get qnt => _controller1.text.trim();
  String get um => _controller2.text.trim();
```

...

```
TextField(
controller: _controller,
),

TextField(
controller: _controller1,
),

TextField(
controller: _controller2,
),

IconButton(
                  color: primaryColor,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: text.isEmpty || um.isEmpty || qnt.isEmpty  ? null : () => _onSubmitted(text, um, qnt),
                ),
```

...

```
  void _onSubmitted(String text, String qnt, String um) {
    if (text.isEmpty || qnt.isEmpty || um.isEmpty) return;

    widget.onSubmitted(text);
    widget.onSubmitted(qnt);
    widget.onSubmitted(um);
    _controller.clear();
    _controller1.clear();
    _controller2.clear();
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }
```

if I fill in the 3 fields with: 1, 2, 3, I have the attached image as output..
instead it should be a single line like: 1 2 3

```
Text(item.name + item.qnt + item.um ),
```

help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is not enough to clarify the problem. It would be great if you can provide code snippet of the `widget.onSubmitted(text)` callback.

But assuming you want to store the **text**, **qnt** and **um** value in a single row, you have to change the callback to something like the following instead of calling it individually with text, qnt, um:

```
widget.onSubmitted(text: text, qnt: qnt, um: um)
```

Answer (score 0):

with your modification I get this error

[immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNth7.jpg)

```
Future<String> createItem(String listId, String name, String qnt, String um) async {
final id = uuid();
final maxPosition = (await _crdt.query('''
  SELECT max(position) AS max_position FROM todos
  WHERE list_id = ? AND is_deleted = 0
''', [listId])).first['max_position'] as int? ?? -1;
await _crdt.execute('''
  INSERT INTO todos (id, list_id, name, qnt, um, done, position, creator_id, created_at)
  VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7, ?8, ?9)
''', [
  id,
  listId,
  name,
  qnt,
  um,
  0,
  maxPosition + 1,
  userId,
  DateTime.now().toUtcString,
]);
return id;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).